# How do I tell a generic class instance about its generic owning collection?

Tags: c#, generics

I have an abstract class "RiskBaseCollection" that uses generics to essentially be a container for a dictionary.  The type of items stored in this dictionary must be passed in the constructor, and they must inherit from a base class called "RiskBase":

I have a method in the dictionary container class that calls a database query to populate the contents of the dictionary (the database call depends on what is set within another field, but that's not important to my point).

When populating the dictionary, for each database record, I want to see whether an appropriate instance of a class has already been created and stored:  If it has, I retrieve it and add additional values to it.  If it hasn't, I create a new instance of the RiskBase class.  I have done this with Generics, such that the correct type of RiskBase is actually created.

What I am struggling with, is that I want to tell each instance of the "RiskBase" class what collection 'owns' it.  I've tried various means, but can't get it to work.

Here is an extract of the Collection class, and the entire RiskBase class:

```
public abstract class RiskBaseCollection<T> where T : RiskBase, new() 
{
    public Dictionary<int, T> Items = new Dictionary<int, T>();

    #region Non-critical stuff
      //Removed - not important to my issue.         
    #endregion

    public void ReadData()
    {
        if (ValidConnectionInfo == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Create the connection:
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ReaderConnectionString))
        {
            if (conn != null) conn.Open();
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(SQL, conn))
                {
                    if (command != null)
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
                            {
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    int RiskID = reader.GetValue<int>("ID");
                                    string Title = reader.GetValue<string>("TITLE");
                                    string Status = reader.GetValue<string>("STATUS");
                                    DateTime RaisedDate = reader.GetValue<DateTime>("RAISED_DATE");
                                    DateTime ExpiryDate = reader.GetValue<DateTime>("EXPIRY_DATE");

                                    //Get the FLOC string for the current record
                                    string FunctionalLocation = reader.GetValue<string>("FUNCTIONAL_LOCATION");

                                    T thisRisk = (Items.ContainsKey(RiskID)) ? (T)Items[RiskID] : new T();
                                    thisRisk.RiskID = RiskID;
                                    thisRisk.Title = Title;
                                    thisRisk.Status = Status;
                                    thisRisk.RaisedDate = RaisedDate;
                                    thisRisk.ExpiryDate = ExpiryDate;
                                    thisRisk.AddFunctionalLocation(FunctionalLocation);
                                    thisRisk.Owner = this;      //<=Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'CRT.Risks.RiskBaseCollection<T>' to 'CRT.Risks.RiskBaseCollection<CRT.Risks.RiskBase>'  
                                    Items[RiskID] = thisRisk;  
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}





public class RiskBase
{
    public RiskBaseCollection<RiskBase> Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual RiskType RiskType { get; set; }

    public RiskBase() { }
    public RiskBase(RiskBaseCollection<RiskBase> riskBaseCollection, RiskType riskType)
    {
        Owner = riskBaseCollection;
        RiskType = riskType;
    }

    public virtual int RiskID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual string Status { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime RaisedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }

    public virtual List<string> FunctionalLocations { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public virtual void AddFunctionalLocation(string functionalLocation)
    {
        if (!FunctionalLocations.Contains(functionalLocation)) FunctionalLocations.Add(functionalLocation);
    }
}
```

Essentially, I'm after a means of setting the "Owner" Property for the RiskBase class.

Comment: Side note: please carefully read [MCVE] guidance on posting code - 95% of code in this post is not related to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `RiskBaseCollection<T>` implement a [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) generic interface, and change the `RiskBase.Owner` property's type to this interface:

```
// new interface
interface IRiskBaseCollection<out T>
{
    // interface members
}

public abstract class RiskBaseCollection<T> : IRiskBaseCollection<T> 
    where T : RiskBase, new() 
{
    // ...
    thisRisk.Owner = this;  // this now compiles!
}

public class RiskBase
{
    public IRiskBaseCollection<RiskBase> Owner { get; set; }    // interface reference
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank-you!  Works great.  I shall now go and read-up to try to understand WHY this works!